# If/while statement doesn't execute (java)

Tags: java, if-statement

I made a `public int` so that it will return a number different from a number of other integers. It should've returned 9, but, it just gives me a random number like the if statement isn't even there.

Here's the code

```
import java.util.*;

static int sum1;
static int sum2 = 1;
static int sum3 = 2;
static int num1 = 3;
static int num2 = 4;
static int num3 = 5;
static int dum1 = 6;
static int dum2 = 7;
static int dum3 = 8;


public static int getNumbers()
{
    int holder;
    boolean numFound = false;
    holder = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 9);

    if (holder == 0) while(numFound = false)
    {
        holder = 1;
        if (holder!=sum1 && holder!=sum2 && holder!=sum3 && holder!=num1 && holder!=num2 && holder!=num3 && holder!=dum1 && holder!=dum2 && holder!=dum3)
        {
            numFound = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (holder!=sum1 && holder!=sum2 && holder!=sum3 && holder!=num1 && holder!=num2 && holder!=num3 && holder!=dum1 && holder!=dum2 && holder!=dum3)
        {
            numFound = true;
        }
    }
    return holder;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    sum1 = getNumbers();
    System.out.println(sum1);

}
```

What's happening and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: When is holder going to equal 0?

Comment: Explain this line `if (holder == 0) while(numFound = false)`. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: It's `while (numFound = false)` that does not execute. It should be either `while (numFound  == false)` or better yet, `while (!numFound)`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: The "if (holder == 0) while (numFound = false)" means that while numFound is equal to false, execute the if statement

Comment: (numFound = false)===>(numFound == false)

Comment: your holder will always be >1 as you are adding the randon number to 1. so if(holder ==0) will never be true, thus else will be executed.

Comment: This question is about a widely occurring "English to java" translation misunderstanding. It is not a typo in the sense that OP would say "Oh yes, obviously, I just missed that." Some explanation is needed. So closing this question as a typo is not appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be simplified to

```
holder = 1; /* or higher */

if (holder == 0)
{ /* all of the "while" ignored, because "if" is not true */
} else
{ /* always executed */
}
```

It does not surprise me that the `if` seems to be ignored.

If you intend to check an if-statement while a condition is true, then the most similar code would be

```
do
{
    if(conditioni)
    { /* then */
    } else
    { /* else */
    }
} while (conditionw);
```

Or by reversing the order

```
while (conditionw)
{
    if(conditioni)
    { /* then */
    } else
    { /* else */
    }
}
```

The details of your logic need to be verified, the order of what gets evaluated when is probably important.

Answer (score 0):

*holder* is initialized with a random number between 1 and 9, the lowest possible value for *holder* is 1, so *holder* will never be zero and following the *if* will never evaluate to *true* and the while loop is never executed.

So with each run the function will only the random value which was assigned to *holder*

```
int holder;
boolean numFound = false;
holder = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 9);

if (holder == 0) while(numFound = false)
```